# Запуск команды на узле отличном от того, на котором исполняется playbook

Tags: ansible

Запускаю плейбук ansible с указанием группы узлов из файла inventory. В процессе выполнения плейбука регистрируются различные variables, по значению которых выбирается узел, на котором выполняется конкретный task.

Конструкция:

```
- name: task name
    become_user: user
    shell: command_to_run parameter1="{{ another_hostname }}.domain.local"
    when: some_variable.stdout == "f" (это значение переменной указывает на конкретный узел, а команду надо выполнить на узле где значение some_variable.stdout == "t")
```

Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Можно форматирование сделать нормальным? Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) для конкретных тасков.

```
---

- hosts: webservers

  tasks:

  - name: task 1
    command: smth

  - name: task 2
    command: smth
    delegate_to: another_host
```

В данном примере `task 1` выполнится на очередном хосте из `webservers`, а `task 2` всегда на `another_host`